# How to monitor time it takes a user to enter data into a input text field in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to programming,

The program I am trying to write has a html page with many input text boxes.  The study I am doing is about how users enter data.

I have tried using on click to pick up time user enter text box.  However just found out that can not store value from with in a javascript function.  Variable time.  tried putting in a bean, and getParameter but neither worked.

Does anyone have a solution for this.

Need a way to store eventually into a flat text file time users spent entering data into each text box by name of each text box.

Thanks

Comment: can you post some code of what you have tried?

Comment: You can certainly store things in variables in Javascript functions. Perhaps you could show your code and we can help you identify the problem.

Comment: A piece of advice that's tangential to your specific question - I would use `onfocus` rather than `onclick`.  The former will fire whenever the field becomes "active" regardless of how it happens, whereas the latter predictably only happens if it's clicked on with the mouse.  Personally I usually tab between fields rather than using the mouse, and this wouldn't fire any click events.

Answer (score 3):

Whipped this together real quick. This has a variable which will hold all the data for each form, by name, and the last time focused. It uses that last time focused to calculate the amount of time it was in focus, on blur.

```
var Status = {};

var focusHandler = function() {
    var name = this.name;
    console.log("Focus", name, Status[name]);
    if (!Status[name]) Status[name] = {
        total: 0,
        focus: Date.now()
    }
    else Status[name].focus = Date.now();
}
var blurHandler = function() {
    var name = this.name;
    if (Status[name]) {
        Status[name].total += Date.now() - Status[name].focus;
    }
}

// You don't have to attach them this way, it's just for example

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0, l = inputs.length; i < l; i++) {
    inputs[i].onfocus = focusHandler;
    inputs[i].onblur = blurHandler;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TjLab/

Answer (score 1):

Onfocus set the start time, onblur set the finish time and calculate the difference. Store the result value in a hidden field. When the form is submitted, read the hidden value on the server.

Do not forget about the use case when the user focus, blurs, and refocuses the textbox.