# Measuring time for input

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, measure

I have a simple quiz form with several inputs and selects, and I need to measure the time it took the contestant to write/choose an answer.

This is what I'm trying, but it reports incorrect time:

```js
$('input, select').on('focus', function(event) {

    el = $(this);

    name = el.attr('name'); // console.log(name);
    a = performance.now();
    a_value = el.val();

    console.log(name + ' focused.');

    $(el).on('input select cut copy paste', function(event) {
        console.log('el: ' + el);
        b_value = el.val();
        if (a_value != b_value) {
            b = performance.now();
            if (name in times) {
                console.log('exists');
                times[name] = times[name] + (b - a);
            } else {
                times[name] = b - a;
            }
        }
    });

    $(el).on('blur', function(event) {
        alert(times);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="text" name="" id="">
  <select name="" id="">
    <option value="">option1</option>
    <option value="">option2</option>
  </select>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you could use this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626044/how-to-monitor-time-it-takes-a-user-to-enter-data-into-a-input-text-field-in-htm?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: What is times in  if (name in times)? It is coming as undefined in console.

Comment: Please fix the snippet

Comment: @Drakes 1) yes, this becomes the key in the array 2) selects also will have value of the `selected` option 3) not really, just like input, select should also increment time depending on how long I interacted with it (was focused, changed the selections etc..). For the "focused" state, I'm thinking adding a timer that stop after x seconds incase the user has the field focused but went away from the PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking with you (the OP), I've made several adjustments to your base code.

First, the `.on('input ...')` was being called every time the form element had focus so event handlers were stacking up. A corresponding `.off('input ...')` is called in the blur handler to handle this.

Next, to make an associative array in JavaScript we normally use objects, so I made `times = {}`.

Next, `times[name] = times[name] + (b - a);` keeps using the initial time value from `a` when the element was first focused, so aggregated time stacks up quickly. We can compensate for this by setting `a = b;` afterwards.

Finally, to keep track of when a select changes much like when the input changes, we can update the internal selected value like `a_value = b_value;` when the selection has changed.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

```js
var times = {};
$('input, select').on('focus', function(event) {
  var el = $(this);

  // This will get the name of the input or select. Is that right?
  // OP: yes, this becomes the key in the array
  var name = el.attr('name');
  var a = performance.now();
  var a_value = el.val();

  // This will attach an event handler over and over unless we 
  // unattach it. Please see "blur" below
  el.on('input select cut copy paste', function(event) {
    var b_value = el.val();

    // Initial values are updated as inputs change
    // so the times don't stack up
    if (a_value !== b_value) {
      b = performance.now();
      if (times.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        console.log('exists');
        times[name] = times[name] + (b - a);
        a = b;
      } else {
        console.log('adding ' + name);
        times[name] = b - a;
      }
      a_value = b_value;
    }
  });

  el.one('blur', function(event) {
    console.dir(times);

    // Update the times display
    displayTimes();

    // Unattach the event handler added in on("focus")
    el.off('input select cut copy paste');
  });

  // For the demo
  function displayTimes() {
    // Output results
    var str = "";
    $.each(times, function(key, value) {
      str += key + " total time: " + value + "<br>";
    });
    $("#results").html(str);
  }

  // Periodically update the times just for the demo
  setInterval(displayTimes, 200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input" id="">
<select name="select" id="">
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
</select>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Although it works great, but I think I'll use tock.js to start, pause, lap and stop timers since I'll have be having too many to handle. Thanks for this though!

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..

```
<script>
  var Stopwatch = (function() {
            var s;
            return {
                settings: {
                    stop: 0,
                    sw: document.querySelectorAll(".stopwatch")[0],
                    results: document.querySelectorAll(".results")[0],
                    mills: 0,
                    secs: 0,
                    mins: 0,
                    i: 1,
                    times: ["00:00:00"],
                    clearButton: "<a href=\"#\" class=\"button\" onClick=\"Stopwatch.clear();\">Clear</a>"
                },
                init: function() {
                    s = this.settings;
                    setInterval(this.timer, 1);
                },
                clear: function() {
                    s.i = 1,
                    s.times = ["00:00:00"],
                    s.results.innerHTML = s.clearButton;
                },
                lap: function() {
                    if (s.i === 1) {
                        s.results.innerHTML = s.clearButton;
                    }
                    s.times.push(("0" + s.mins).slice(-2) + ":"
                                         + ("0" + s.secs).slice(-2) + ":"
                                         + ("0" + s.mills).slice(-2));
                    var diffTime = ("0" + Math.floor(s.times[s.i].split(":")[0]
                                             - s.times[s.i-1].split(":")[0])).slice(-2)
                                             + ":"
                                             + ("0" + Math.floor(s.times[s.i].split(":")[1]
                                             - s.times[s.i-1].split(":")[1])).slice(-2)
                                             + ":"
                                             + ("0" + (s.times[s.i].split(":")[2]
                                             - s.times[s.i-1].split(":")[2])).slice(-2);
                    s.results.innerHTML = s.results.innerHTML + "<tr><td>"
                                                            + s.times[s.i] + "</td><td>"
                                                            + diffTime + "</td></tr>";
                    s.i++;
                },
                restart: function() {
                    s.mills = 0,
                    s.secs = 0,
                    s.mins = 0;
                    this.start();
                },
                start: function() {
                    s.stop = 0;
                },
                stop: function() {
                    s.stop = 1;
                },
                timer: function() {
                    if (s.stop === 0) {
                        if (s.mills === 100) {
                            s.secs++;
                            s.mills = 0;
                        }
                        if (s.secs === 60) {
                            s.mins++;
                            s.secs = 0;
                        }
                        s.sw.innerHTML = ("0" + s.mins).slice(-2) + ":"
                                                     + ("0" + s.secs).slice(-2) + ":"
                                                     + ("0" + s.mills).slice(-2);
                        s.mills++;
                    }
                }
            };
        })();
$('.textbox,.selectbox').focusin(function(event) {
 Stopwatch.init();
Stopwatch.restart();    
});
$('.textbox,.selectbox').on('blur', function(event) {
    Stopwatch.stop();
});
```

[Working Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/TjLab/8/)

[References](http://codepen.io/_Billy_Brown/pen/dbJeh)

Comment: Not exactly what I want, but the stopwatch reference is helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've made simple jquery plugin for this. It is able to tell you what is the total edit time (only when edit was actually in use), first edit time and last edit time for any input element. You can also get all edit times.

```
(function () {
    var getTime = function () { return performance.now(); };
    function MeasureTime () {
        this.editTimes = [];
        this.currentEdit = null;
        this.lastEdit = {start:0, last: 0};
        this.firstEdit = 0;
    }
    MeasureTime.prototype = {
        setFirst: function () {
            this.firstEdit = getTime();
            this.setFirst = new Function();
        },
        startEdit: function (val) {
            this.setFirst();
            if(this.currentEdit == null) {
                this.currentEdit = {start: getTime(), last: getTime(), value: val};
                this.editTimes.push(0);
            } else {
                this.edit(val);
            }
        },
        edit: function (val) {
            if(this.currentEdit == null)
                  this.startEdit(val);
            else {
                var current = this.currentEdit;
                if(current.value == val)
                    return;
                current.last = getTime();
                this.editTimes.pop();
                this.editTimes.push(current.last - current.start);
            }
        },
        stopEdit: function () {
            if(this.currentEdit != null) {
                this.lastEdit = this.currentEdit;
                this.currentEdit = null;
            }
        },
        getEvent: function () {
            return new TimeMeasuredEvent(this.editTimes, this.currentEdit || this.lastEdit, this.firstEdit);
        }
    };
    function TimeMeasuredEvent (all, current, first) {
        this.all = all.slice(0);
        this.start = current.start;
        this.last = current.last;
        this.first = first;
    }
    TimeMeasuredEvent.prototype = {
        current: function () {
            return this.all[this.all.length-1];
        },
        total: function () {
            var sum = 0, a = this.all, l = a.length, i = -1;
            while(++i<l)
                sum+=a[i];
            return sum;
        }
    };
    function EnsureMeasureTime () {
        if (typeof(this.measureTimeData) === "undefined") {
            var mtd = this.measureTimeData = new MeasureTime();
            $(this).on('focus', function () {
                mtd.startEdit(this.value);
        $(this).on('input.measuretime select.measuretime cut.measuretime copy.measuretime paste.measuretime', function () {
           mtd.edit(this.value);
           $(this).trigger('timeMeasured', [mtd.getEvent()]); 
        });
            $(this).on('blur', function () {
                mtd.stopEdit();
                $(this).trigger('timeMeasured', [mtd.getEvent()]); 
                $(this).off('measuretime');
            });
        });
        }
    }
    $.fn.measureTime = function () {
        $(this).each(EnsureMeasureTime);
        return this;
    };
})();
```

Sample usage ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jerh8xv4/4/)):

```
var inputs = $('input, select');
inputs.measureTime();
var all = {};
inputs.on('timeMeasured', function (ev, data) {
    console.log(ev, data);
    all[ev.target.name] = data.total();
    console.log("First edit time: " + data.first);
    console.log("Last edit time: " + data.last);
    console.log("All edits durations: " + data.all.join(", "));
    console.log("Current edit duration: " + data.current());
    console.log("Total edit duration: " + data.total());
    var s = "";
    for(var n in all) {
        s+= n + ": " + all[n]+"\n";
    }
    $("#times").text(s);
});
```

You can also access raw MeasureTime object by `element.measureTimeData` to get edit times.

Answer (score 0):

You can find what I tried in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3jgs1fbv/).
The main point to me is that you were adding up times over and over again, since the initial time was not changing and you were adding the answering time more than once.

```
if (name in times) {
    console.log('exists');
    times[name] = times[name] + (b - a);
    //here you already had added (b1 - a) with b1 < b
    //either you reset 'a' here or you store the diff in a variable and sum it up at the end
} else {
    times[name] = b - a;
}
```

I stored the answering time in a variable and added to the array on `blur` and tried to be as consistent as possible with your original approach.

There are still a couple of things I miss, though. Which is mainly related with cheating. As far as I got you want to count only the real changing time (from `focus` to the last `input`, say, not counting the time from the last `input` to `blur` and definitely not the time looking at the page and maybe writing the answer in a wordpad environment).

In a fair and safe system you should, IMHO, consider the time someone can look at the quiz more than the time s/he is actually writing the answer. But this obviously depends on what the quiz is made for!